# Should I disable Content-Security-Policy header for images?

Tags: image, http-headers, content-security-policy

As Content-Security-Policy header is used to mainly prevent [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), I think it wouldn't matter if I disable it for .png, .jpg, .ico and .webp files. As they do not in general do not contain HTML.

### But what I noticed is:

When I don't disable CSP header on image files, it disallows the browser from providing the HTML layout for the image file when visiting it directly, for example, I mean: When you visit  example.com/image.jpg, in chrome, the image has a black background behind it, and it is centered onto the screen. But, when I turn on CSP, every style that for example, chrome provides for the image when the user visits it, is invalid, because CSP blocks it.

### Now, my question is:

Should I disable CSP header for image files? I do not see any *clear* disadvantages of disabling it for image files, but I just want to make sure before I do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I disable CSP header for image files? I do not see any clear disadvantages of disabling it for image files, but I just want to make sure before I do so.

Yes, you should disable CSP header for image files, it does not work when delivered with the png/jpg/ico etc... files.
The only thing you can delivery images and video accompanied with `frame-ancestors` directive, this prevents these files to be [embedded info `<iframe>` `<object>`](https://csplite.com/csp/test352/#test) tags but not into `<img>` / `<video>` tags.

CSP should be published for HTML/XSLT files only, for other MIME-types it does not work.
Note: To specify a Content Security Policy for the worker you need to [publish CSP header with worker JS-file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#csp_in_workers).

> **[This XSS via images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65851127/12865944) example abt.**

Do not worry in vain.

1. This XSS is not via image file, actually COMMENTS inside the image was treated as HTML because `accounts.shopify.com` server did not check MIME-types upon upload files. Because of that an image was loaded and marked as text/html and therefore server sends it to browser as HTML.
2. Such images fail to work inside the `<img>` tag, just insert "poisoned" image and have a look.
3. The `img-src` directive does not protect against such things. Anyway such images will fall under `'self'` token allowance. Do not use `'unsafe-inline'` in `script-src` that's all.

Answer (score 5):

CSPs are Good.  From MDN:

> https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/
>
> Instead of blindly trusting everything that a server delivers, CSP
> defines the Content-Security-Policy HTTP header, which allows you to
> create an allowlist of sources of trusted content, and instructs the
> browser to only execute or render resources from those sources.

If you're using CSPs at all, then you should use them across the board.  Yes, image files might be "less vulnerable".  But they can still be an "attack vector".  For example: https://hackerone.com/reports/964550

Rather than "disabling CSP", you might wish to use img-src:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/img-src
>
> The HTTP Content-Security-Policy img-src directive specifies valid
> sources of images and favicons.